# como manejar directorios y archivos en linux

Tags: linux

¿Como se manejan los directorios y archivos en linux? aqui te comparto algo que yo e documentado , si me equivoque o algo por el estilo no olvide corregirme.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Crear un archivo y directorio.--

Arhcivo  = cat > nombre archvio [ruta si es deseada] <---> touch name.txt ( aqui no se tiene que escribir contenido )
Directorio = mkdir nombreCarpeta [ruta si es deseada]

--Copiar archivo y directorio--

Archivo = cp nombre [ruta completa] Ejemplo : cp test.text /home/dagemov/Documentos/
Directorio = cp -r ---> En los directorios debemos hacer un copiado de forma recurvisa , etnonces
         Ejemplo :  cp -r carpeta /home/dagemov/Escritorio/ ---> Aqui copiamos la carpeta "carpeta" en el escritorio.

--Borrar arhcivo y directorio--

algunas opciones de borrado:
 -v -r -f -i   ---< -v = muestra lo que se borra   -i=solicita confirmacion de borrar -r=borrado recursiva -f=rompe todo y fuerza

Archivo = rm -vi name.txt
Directori = rm -vri nombreCarpeta

--Permisos de archivos y directorios--

Para mirar que permisos tiene una carpeta o archivo hacemos el siguiente listado :  (ls -l), el cual nos muestras de forma detallada
el listado de lo que hay en ese directorio

tipos de permisos : 
    -r =  leer
    -w = escribir
    -x = ejecutable
    
    <Un permiso se puede denegar poniendo un ( - ) en vez de una letra .>

Debemos tener algo claro y es que para saber como asignar los permisos , debemos tener en cuenta la siguiente estructura:

    En los permisos hay 9 " espacio " y de estos 9 se dividen en 3 para los siguientes bloques de permisos :
        Usuario = 3 
        Grupos = 3
        Otros = 3 
    Cada bloque contiene 3 espacios para asignar los permisos. Ahora bien vamos a ver como funciona

Archivo = Para asignar el permiso a un archivo , debemos decirle al computador que es un archivo , entonces colocamos de primero :
    (-) , el cual es el indentificador de un archivo
    archivoPruebaLectura.txt ---> nuestro archivo de prueba :)
    Usaremos la palabra recervada chmod , para darle los permisos al archivo creado o que deseemos
    
    chmod -rw- rw- r-- archivoPruebaLectura.txt
    el primer ( - ) significa que es un archivo , luego le damos permiso de leer, escribir y omitimos el ejecutar
    , dado a que no es un archivo ejecutable ( estos fueron los permisos del usuario)
    Grupo = rw-  pueden leer , escrbir y no ejecutar
    Otros = Los que no pertenezcan al grupo solo pueden leer

Directorio = Se identifica con (d) iniciando
    Ejemplo : carpetaPrueba
    chmod drwx rwx r-x carpetaPrueba
    usuario : lee , escribe y ejecuta
    Grupo : lee , escribe y ejecuta
    Otros : pueden leer y ejecutar 

    Notacion : los permisos tambien se pueden escrbir de forma binaria , osea es decir que podemos aplicar matematicas discretas
        
        Ejemplo : donde se encuentre una letra se colocara un 1 y donde se encuentre un (-) se coloca 0
        
        -rw- rw- r--
         110 110 100
          6   6   4
        ENTONCES : chmod 664 archivoPruebaLectura.txt --> el mismo resultado que el anterior comando que hicimos
```

Comment: el formato es extraño, cuesta leer. Creo que para hacer pregunta con autorespuesta deberías formular algo más concreto, o bien algo más encontrable. Ahora corre el riesgo de caer en el mar de preguntas sin apenas visualizaciones